# C# Как запустить процесс в процессе?

Tags: c#, процесс, рефлексия

Можно ли как-то в c# запустить процесс в процессе без создания нового процесса?

У меня есть (.exe) программа, которая принимает аргументы через cmdline и она написана не на C#.  Можно ли эту программу запустить типа как через рефлексию, если она написана не на c#? Или обязательно нужно запускать сторонний процесс?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет, через рефлексию можно запускать лишь управляемые сборки. Запустить другое неуправляемое приложение в рамках вашего процесса при очень большой необходимости можно, используя очень грязные трюки (например, [вот](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1045674/Load-EXE-as-DLL-Mission-Possible)), но лучше так не делать. Я бы посоветовал просто запустить отдельный процесс.